# Excel VBA For Each Loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, foreach, logic

I am having a bit of trouble with a for-each loop with If statements inside of it.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim rng1 As range
Dim cell1 As range
Set rng1 = range("A1")

Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each cell1 In rng1

    While rng1.Rows.Count > 1

        If cell1.Value >= 6000 And cell1.Value < 8000 Then
            range("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            range("B1:B5").Formula = "=(CEILING($A$10*(1+$A$11+$A$12),5))/4"
            Set rng1 = rng1.Resize(4)

        ElseIf cell1.Value >= 4000 And cell1.Value < 6000 Then
            range("2:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            range("4:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            range("B1:B4").Formula = "=(CEILING($A$10*(1+$A$11+$A$12),5))/3"
            range("B5:B5").ClearContents
            Set rng1 = rng1.Resize(3)

        ElseIf cell1.Value >= 2000 And cell1.Value < 4000 Then
            range("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            range("3:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            range("B1:B3").Formula = "=(CEILING($A$10*(1+$A$11+$A$12),5))/2"
            range("B4:B5").ClearContents
            Set rng1 = rng1.Resize(2)

        ElseIf cell1.Value >= 0 And cell1.Value < 2000 Then
            range("2:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            range("B1:B1").Formula = "=(CEILING($A$10*(1+$A$11+$A$12),5))"
            range("B2:B5").ClearContents

        End If
    Wend
Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Basically I want it to do this but its not working correctly:
It looks a range. If that range's value is between 4000 and 6000 then it unhides 3 rows, hides the 4th row, sets the 3 visible rows equal to the formula and divides the ranges value between the 3 rows equally, clears the contents of the hidden rows, then sets the original range it was looking at equal to the range of visible rows (this is where i think im getting hung up in my logic). Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Reassignment of `range` is a bad idea.

Comment: if your range is C1 then what is the point of looping?

Comment: Sorry the range was supposed to start as A1 and then be changed to the range of visible A rows. Bathsheba, how would you go about modifying the code so that the range the for each loop is looking at is always equal to the range of visible rows based on the if statement?

Comment: Use `.Offset()` and/or `.Resize()` with `Range("A1")` to get a reference to the cells you want.

Comment: thanks ja72, that solves my reassignment problem of the range but I am still having trouble with it processing correctly, I think there is a flaw with where i placed the set range = range.Resize(...) within the loop I also get the feeling that i might need a do while counter in there somewhere, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a) What happens if Cell A1 = 5000 and Cell A2 = 3000? Which code block will be executed? Is there a conflict?

b) You have used range as a variable. Use a different name. "range" must be a reserved word. Range with R capital has to be used for declaring some name as a Range object.

c) I noticed one A43:A4. This is a typo i guess - should be A3:A4?

Comment: I fixed the code: the A columns will have a formula in them for =Sum which will basically just sum the value of the visible B columns that have the formula that is in the code. G5 is where I will change the number which will in return change the resulting values of the formulas in the B column which will in turn change the values within the A column and effectively the values which range is looking at. I just used "range" as the variable as an example, fixed in the original post tho.